# CSS conflict within a span - can't fix. Any offer a solution?

Tags: css, button, css-selectors

I have a radio button with text next to and a label wrapped around so that when the text or button are clicked it becomes active.

When inactive, I want part of the text to be standard colour and some of the other text a different colour so I have a span inside that span.

Once active, the style changes on the text to make it a bolder font and all orange. But the inner span goes unaffected.

Can anybody help? Alternative to span on inner text?

```
<label class="label-name">
    <input type="radio" name="group1" class="class-name" />
    <span>Lorem <span class="light-grey">Ipsum</span></span>
</label>
```

&

```
.class-name input:checked + span {
  font-family: "bold-font-family", sans-serif;  
  color: #f26900 !important;
}

.light-grey {
  color: #838383;
  display: inline;
}
```

Styling the whole line of text in a p tag won't work for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below to apply the style to the inner `span` also.

```
:checked + span, :checked + span > span {
  font-family: "bold-font-family", sans-serif;  
  color: #f26900;
}
```

`+`  is for selecting the adjacent sibling directly after the `input`. `>` is to select the child `span` of the `span` that is the adjacent sibling of the `input`.

[**Sample Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/bsdSj/)